# NG2005: The class 'PredService' cannot be created via dependency inject. & NG2003: No suitable inject. token for param. 'data' of class 'PredService'

Tags: angular

I see this is a recurrent topic in Angular but could not find a solution for my case.

I have the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface PredictionInputs {
  birthDate: Date;
  HCP: boolean;
  dayOnes: {
    dayOne: Date;
    approx: boolean;
  }[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PredService {

  constructor(data: PredictionInputs) { 
    console.log(data);
  }
 
}
```

and the following component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PredService as PredictionService, PredictionInputs } from 'src/app/services/pred.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.page.scss'],
  providers: [PredictionService],
})

export class TestPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private prediction: PredictionService) {
    const dayOnes = [];
    dayOnes.push({ dayOne: new Date('2023-05-22'), approx: false });
    dayOnes.push({ dayOne: new Date('2023-04-15'), approx: false });

    const ex7: PredictionInputs = {
      birthDate: new Date('1985-06-05'),
      HCP: false,
      dayOnes: dayOnes,
    };

    this.prediction = new PredictionService(ex7);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }
}
```

Angular says:

*Either add the @Injectable() decorator to 'PredService', or configure a different provider (such as a provider with 'useFactory').*

although I have the @Injectable() decorator in front of 'PredService'... Any Ideas

EDIT:

Following @Derrick's response below I've modified the code as follows:

PredService Class:

```
export class PredService {

  constructor() { 
    //console.log(data);
  }
  getPrediction(data: PredictionInputs) {
    console.log(data);
  } 
}
```

TestPage Class:

```
...
//this.prediction = new PredictionService(ex7);
    this.prediction.getPrediction(ex7);
```

Now it works, but honestly I don't fully understand why. Why I need the method getPrediction? can't I have the console.log(data) statement in the constructor?

Comment: The problem is caused by the `data` argument to the `PredService` constructor. There is nothing injectable that matches the `PredectionInputs` class. Is that intended to be configuration? If so, you can create an instance of it and provide it to the injector using an injection token: https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken

Comment: I'm migrating a javascript class I wrote to Angular. In the above example I'm only console logging, in the actual implementation there's some validation and processing of the data received by the constructor followed by calls to private class methods that do some calculations. In other words, all the work is done upon class instantiation, and then the results can be retrieved via getter methods.

Comment: The way you're using PredService is a kin to a model. You're already injecting the service within the constructor arguments, no need to assign it again with a new instance passing in data.

Since we're dependency injecting this, I would suggest creating a class that would perform similarily for the assignment of `this.prediction`.

Comment: The question you need to answer is: what code is used to instantiate and hydrate an instance of `PredictionInputs`. It isn't necessary to use dependency injection for everything. If it contains static values that don't need to be read from a server, you can just import it.

Comment: @Jack: I don't fully understand your suggestion. PredictionInputs are not static, they are user inputs. The class needs to perform some calculations based on these prediction inputs. I can use the working alternative I published under "EDIT", but still doesn't make sense to me. I suppose that what I'd like to understand is why can't I console.log directly in the constructor? Why do I need to use a "helper" class to do so?

Comment: The answer to "where does it come from" is exactly what I was trying to get you to think about. The answer to that question determines how you need to pass that data to your service. Now that you've considered that, you've been able to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the explanation. It was not obvious for me, so publishing it here just in case helps someone else:

The reason why the first set of code does not work as expected is that it is intended to create a new instance of the PredictionService within the component's constructor using the new keyword. However, this is not how dependency injection works in Angular.

In Angular, when a service is injected into a component, the Angular dependency injection system automatically creates an instance of the service and passes it to the component's constructor as a parameter. This means that the prediction parameter in the component's constructor is already an instance of the PredictionService, and there is no need to create another one.

To pass data to the PredictionService instance that is injected into the component, a method in the PredictionService class that takes the data as a parameter and performs the necessary actions should be created. Then, this method can be called from the component after injecting the service, as shown in the working example.

It's not recommended to access the data from the constructor of the Service because the constructor should be used only for dependency injection and not for logic.

```
export class PredService {

  constructor() { 
    // The constructor should only be used for dependency injection
  }

  processData(data: PredictionInputs) {
    console.log(data);
    // Perform the necessary logic with the data here
  }
}
```